# Spring RestController Post method not work but get method works

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

This is my RestController, the get method works but post method doesn't work.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/workpackages")
public class RESTWorkPackageController {

    @Autowired
    private WorkPackageService service;

    @GetMapping()
    public DataTableResponse<WorkPackage> findWorkPackage(DataTableRequest dataTableRequest) {
        return service.findWorkPackage(dataTableRequest);
    }

    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<?> addWorkPackage(@RequestBody WorkPackage workPackage) {
        WorkPackage w = service.addWorkPackage(workPackage);
        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(w.getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }


}
```

This is my request on angular client:

```
addWorkpackage(workpackage: WorkPackage): Observable<WorkPackage> {
        return this.http.post<WorkPackage>(`${URL.Workpackages}/`, workpackage);
    }

    getWorkpackages(request: DataTableRequest): Observable<DataTableResponse> {
        return this.http.get<DataTableResponse>(`${URL.Workpackages}/`, {params: request as any});
    }
```

Get request works, but post method  is not invoked.
why does this happen?

UPDATE: 
This is Java code for WorkPackage class:

```
Entity
@Table(name = "workpackages")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class WorkPackage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "workpackage_id")
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "workpackage_number", unique = true)
    @Size(max = 8)
    private String workpackageNumber;

    @Column(name = "title")
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "objective")
    @Size(max = 250)
    private String objective;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;
}
```

This is WorkPackage in JS class

```
export class WorkPackage {

    constructor(workpackage?) {
        workpackage = workpackage || {};
        this.id = workpackage.id || null;
        this.workpackageNumber = workpackage.workpackageNumber || '';
        this.objective = workpackage.objective || '';
        this.project = workpackage.project || null;
    }

    id: number;
    workpackageNumber: string;
    title: string;
    objective: string;
    project: Project;
}
```

and this is a JSON body example:

{"id":null,
"workpackageNumber":"21",
"objective":"test",
"project":{"id":1,"title":"test","acronym":"tt","code":"022","startDate":"2017-03-13","endDate":"2017-04-17","owner":null},"title":"Prova wp"}

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by ` not invoked` ? The call to your backend is done ? The backend returns nothing ? Do you see your call pending in your navigator network ?

Comment: In the console server I see nothing, no error. I also tried to put a System.out.println in the post method, but the printing is not done.

Comment: Does any exception raises in the console? If yes, post the stacktrace on your question

Comment: There is no exception in the console.

Answer (score 0):

May be "Spring Boot" cannot mapped the request body with your model, what do you see in  server console?

Comment: In the console server I see nothing, no error. I also tried to put a System.out.println in the post method, but the printing is not done.

Answer (score 0):

can you post the error logs from the Spring boot service please? Most likely scenario is that the `workpackage` json in the request does not comply with the `WorkPackage` pojo in the server side.

Can you post sample JSON body for the `POST` request as well as the Java code for `WorkPackage` class?